# Can i change this in code into css

Tags: css

```
<div class="rotate"> <img src="image_url"/> </div>
```

I want to set this img src image to background image in css. please help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Which code? which background image? Please clarify a bit more...

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about how to set background image to class 'rotate' instead of calling img src.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.rotate
 {
 background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center;     
 width:100px;
 height:100px;  
 }
</style>
<div class="rotate"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML wise would be:

```
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

and css would be

```
.rotate {   // define a class in css
    background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center; // asuming you dont want it repeat and centered in the middle of your div.
    width: *amount of pixels*;
    height: *amount of pixels*;
}
```

As a note, i'd like to point out that an image just as background added won't work, cause there is no size defined, thus you ll end up, if i look now at your code, with a blank image, because the div size is not set. It will render your div with a 0px by 0px width and height. I added a width and height to the size you have to set. Setting the width and height will work with pixels and em.